# Pass data from Vue front end to Node/Express backend

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I want a user to be able to enter a city into a text input at the '/' route. Once that is submitted, id like to redirect to '/result' and show the info. The only way I can get '/result' to show what I want is if I hard code a city in the back end. How do I eliminate this?

GET request

```
app.get('/result', (req, res) => {
    let city = 'Portland';
    let url = `${process.env.BASEURL}${city}&units=imperial&APPID=${process.env.API_KEY}`;

axios.get(url)
    .then(response => { res.json(response.data) })
    .catch(error => {
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        })
    });
});
```

Service file that passes data from backend API

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = "http://localhost:5000/result";

class WeatherService {
    static getWeather() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get(url).then((res) => {
                try {
                    resolve(res.data);
                } catch (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

export default WeatherService;
```

Front end

```
<template>
<div>
  <p class="error" v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
  <i class="fa fa-times close-icon none"></i>
  <main>
    <div class="location none">
      <div class="city">{{ weather.name }}</div>
      <div class="long-lat">{{ weather.coord.lon }}, {{ weather.coord.lat }}</div>
      <div class="date">-, -:- pm</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content none">
      <div class="tempIcon">
        <div class="condition-icon"></div>
        <div class="temp">{{ weather.main.temp }}<span>°</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="weather">{{ weather.weather[0].main }}</div>
      <div class="hi-low">{{ weather.main.temp_max }}° / {{ weather.main.temp_minl }}° <span></span>Feels like {{ weather.main.feels_like }}°</div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <section class="details">
    <div class="humidity none">
        <i class="fa fa-tint"></i>
        <h5>Humidity</h5>
        <p class="humidity-value">{{ weather.main.humidity }}%</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pressure none">
        <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
        <h5>Pressure</h5>
        <p class="pressure-value">{{ weather.main.pressure }} hPa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wind none">
        <i class="fa fa-wind"></i>
        <h5>Wind</h5>
        <p class="wind-value">{{ weather.wind.speed }} mph</p>
    </div>
  </section>  
</div>

</template>

<script>
import WeatherService from '../WeatherService';

export default {
  name: 'Result',
  data(){
    return {
      weather: [],
      error: ''
    }
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      this.weather = await WeatherService.getWeather();
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error.message;
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass some parameters like this

```js
axios.get('/result', {
    params: {
      city: 'Portland'
    }
  })
```

This, of course, will need to be forwarded to your function to make it dynamic.

You can also use some headers or make a `POST` request rather than a `GET`. Not sure of the real differences between all those solutions tho.

Comment: When you say that it will need to be forwarded to my function, what do you mean exactly? I'm still a noob!

Comment: Pass the argument `{ city: 'Portland' }` as an argument to the function, to `getWeather` and your `GET request`.